# swift cell automatically selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have created a tableview, please find attached the screenshot[TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFw3B.jpg)

the problem is that if i select the first item in section 1, if i scroll down another one is selected automatically. Here is my code for cellForItemAt:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        var cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "selectStory", for: indexPath) as! StorySelectionTableViewCell

        cell1.label.text = self.myStories[indexPath.row].name!
        cell1.select.tag = indexPath.row
        cell1.select.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSwitch), for: .valueChanged)
        return cell1
    case 1:
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell
        cell.selectSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.thumb.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.thumb.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumb.frame.height / 2
        cell.thumb.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.name.text = myGroups[indexPath.row].name
        cell.selectSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonPress), for: .valueChanged)
        if myGroups[indexPath.row].imageUrl != "" && myGroups[indexPath.row].imageUrl != nil {

            let url = URL(string: myGroups[indexPath.row].imageUrl!)
            cell.thumb.kf.setImage(with: url)

        }
        return cell

    case 2:
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell
        cell.selectSwitch.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.thumb.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.thumb.layer.cornerRadius = cell.thumb.frame.height / 2
        cell.thumb.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.name.text = myUsers[indexPath.row].name
        cell.selectSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonPress), for: .valueChanged)
        if myUsers[indexPath.row].imageUrl != "" && myUsers[indexPath.row].imageUrl != nil {

            let url = URL(string: myUsers[indexPath.row].imageUrl!)
            cell.thumb.kf.setImage(with: url)

        }
        return cell

            //Access itemsB[indexPath.row]
    default:
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactsTableViewCell
        return cell
            //Access itemsC[indexPath.row]
    }


}
```

and here is my Switch Handler:

```
    @objc func handleButtonPress(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let buttonPosition: CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.collectionView)
    let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)


    switch indexPath!.section {
    case 1:
        if self.selectedGroups.contains(self.myGroups[indexPath!.row].id!) {
            //remove it
            self.selectedGroups = self.selectedGroups.filter {
                $0 != self.myGroups[indexPath!.row].id!
            }
        } else {
            self.selectedGroups.append(self.myGroups[indexPath!.row].id!)
        }
        break
    case 2:
        if self.selectedUsers.contains(self.myUsers[indexPath!.row].id!) {
            self.selectedUsers = self.selectedUsers.filter {
                $0 != self.myUsers[indexPath!.row].id!
            }

        } else {
            self.selectedUsers.append(self.myUsers[indexPath!.row].id!)
        }
        break

    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Its just between section 1 and 2. Section 0 is working fine

Comment: why you are repeating same code ? in cellForRow

Comment: what is selectSwitch ?

Comment: selectSwitch is a UISwitch, i'm repeating because i'm just testing how i can solve the issue (later i will cleanup the code, but thats not the problem)

Comment: You know TableView reuse cells ... thats why your switch remain on for the other cell you scroll to

Comment: so turn On switch or Turn off ... on the basis of dataArray that you are using ...

Comment: ok i understand, but how can i fix the issue

Comment: thanks @jawadAli that solved my problem.

Comment: please accept if it resolve the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213368/discussion-between-jawadali-and-dominik-hartl).

Comment: is there any issue sir?

Comment: hey ... @Dominik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or one thing you can do is ... go to `ContactsTableViewCell` class and override this method

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        selectSwitch.setOn(false, animated: false)
         super.prepareForReuse()
    }
```